# Present distances between planet. How can I find them?

Tags: planet, observational-astronomy, distances

It's "commonly known" how distant are our solar system planets from Sun. But we can't easily say that about planets, which distances can differ greatly, without some observations (or simulations, knowing their state in some moment in time).

How can I can check 'actual' relative distances or positions of planets?

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488 may help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ask Wolfram Alpha. [Here is an example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=How%20far%20is%20Mars%20from%20Jupiter%20right%20now?).

Comment: I love Wolfram. It does everything.

Comment: I second that !

Answer (score 4):

[JPL's HORIZONS](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi#top) system should be a fairly good starting point to calculate [ephemerides](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?ephemerides).