# Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?

Tags: amateur-observing, positional-astronomy, resource-request

What resources are available to find the positions of planets, stars,
moons, artificial satellites, asteroids, and other heavenly bodies?

Comment: I was sleeping under the stars with a program called redeye... taught me star trivia like Vega and all the constellations. It tilts and zooms and has labels.

Answer (score 46):

There are many resources online, so this is a community wiki
answer. Please feel free to add to it!

- If you want to visualize the stars/planets/etc (as viewed from Earth
  or another location), you are looking for **planetarium software**:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetarium_software
- If you want accurate positions for stars/planets/etc, you are looking
  for **horizons**:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPL_Horizons_On-Line_Ephemeris_System

http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons

- If you want to **compute** star/planet positions yourself, you have
  several options:

  - SPICE (http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/tutorials.html) will give you
    results that match HORIZONS very closely. You can also use some of
    SPICE's functionality online at
    http://wgc.jpl.nasa.gov:8080/webgeocalc/#NewCalculation
  - SPK (Spice kernel) files are available at https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/ -- while these are primarily intended for use with CSPICE, the format is documented and you can use it directly. It's described at https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/issues/19 and implemented in Python at https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/python-jplephem/tree/master/jplephem
  - If you want to do the SPICE computations yourself (numerically solving the differential equations), see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/13491/21
  - You might also want to use an n-body simulator to do the computations yourself: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25241/what-open-source-n-body-codes-are-available-and-what-are-their-features
  - IAU SOFA (http://www.iausofa.org/) will give you the International
    Astronomical Union's "official" libraries to compute positions.
  - VSOP theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSOP_%28planets%29) is
    another option.
  - PyEphem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyEphem), which derives
    from MIT's libastro library
    (https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/project/xephem/src/xephem-3.5.2/libastro/)
  - Skyfield: https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield
  - libnova (http://libnova.sourceforge.net/)
  - If you want to treat planetary orbits as simple ellipses and ignore perturbations, you can find orbital elements at https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/txt/p_elem_t1.txt but you'll probably want to visit https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?bodies#elem first
  - [VSOP87-multilang](https://github.com/gmiller123456/vsop87-multilang) Implements the VSOP87 theory in over a dozen different programming languages.

Note that these computational libraries don't always agree with each
other or with planetarium software:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293146

- If you want a **catalog** of stars/etc, NOMAD
  (http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/nomad) and GAIA (http://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/) are
  the largest such catalogs (about 1 billion entries each, lots of overlap). The NOMAD link also provides references to smaller catalogs.
- For star **names**, https://www.iau.org/public/themes/naming_stars/ has an official list and Stellarium has several lists in the subdirectories of https://github.com/Stellarium/stellarium/tree/master/skycultures in files named star_names.fab (including the official IAU list)
- For high-resolution **astrophotography** try ALADIN (http://aladin.u-strasbg.fr/#AladinLite)
- If you want to find artificial satellites and spacecraft, start at
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set
- **Transits** of Mercury and Venus across the Sun? http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/transit/transit.html
- Planetary **conjunctions**?
  http://laps.noaa.gov/albers/ast/conjun/conjun.html
- **Occultations** of stars by asteroids? The International Occultation
  Timing Association (IOTA) at http://occultations.org/
- Create your own **Sun-Earth-Moon model** by using a ~17 inches (~44 cm) beach ball or box as the Sun, 4-5 mm object like a pencil eraser as the Earth and a 1 mm sized drill bit or other object to represent the Moon. Then, find a 150-foot string or tape measure. The sun and earth are ~154 feet (~46m) apart. The earth and moon are ~4.7 inches (12 cm) apart.

Comment: I also use SIMBAD (http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fid) if I want to do a quick search for a star or galaxy based on its identifier, and you can also do the reverse and searching for coordinates too.

Comment: I like this one for seeing what's overhead http://www.ucolick.org/~bolte/AY4_00/weblab/project/chart.html .

Comment: That appears to be a framed verison of http://www.fourmilab.ch/yoursky/ -- feel free to add the latter link above.

Comment: @barrycarter I wonder if astroquery mentioned [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30654/12102) and [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33003/planets-positions-azimuth-altitude-api#comment61048_33003) could be added as well?

Comment: @uhoh This is a community wiki answer, so please feel free to add them yourself. But, if you run into trouble, let me know and I'll add them.

Comment: @barrycarter okay I'll give it a try tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: For Python, `astropy` might be useful here as well: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/solarsystem.html

Answer (score 8):

To add to the excellent answer by barrycarter, there are 2 planetarium-like codes, that I know of, that run on a mac and would make excellent tools for viewing certain astronomical objects. The codes are [Stellarium](http://stellarium.org/) and [Celestia](https://celestia.space/). Both turn your computer into your own planetarium where you can search and view objects in space.

Comment: It's actually a public wiki answer (not all my content), so you can add to it directly if you'd like. I had considered listing individual planetarium software (Stellarium is my favorite), but thought linking to the wikipedia list page may be more useful and neutral.

Comment: The second program is called "Celestia" not "Celestial".

Comment: Celestia even lets you move around different from Stellarium which is more like a planetarium-theatre