# Fast moving southward tracking light

Tags: light

At about 4.15 am this morning a light travelling in a southerly direction passed over Adelaide South Australia. It was travelling 10 - 15 times the speed of an Airliner. The light was constant and moving in a straight line

Comment: The most common reason is that you saw a satellite, reflecting sun light.
And not all satellites move at the equator.

Comment: Skim the "how to identify" section of http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488 to see if anyone else saw it.