# Star map, where?

Tags: space

I have been looking at the website https://thenightsky.com and wanted to create a star map my self, from a specific place on a specific date. Where would I be able to find this?

Comment: Start with http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/ and see if that helps

Comment: Wow, they make money on that? You can use the open source program 'stellarium', it's free.

Comment: Stellarium. Install it, enter the location in the settings, change the date / time, print out the map. http://www.stellarium.org/

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, download and install the free app Stellerium. You can input the location and date of interest and it will display the sky. The app is like having your own planetarium. There is another similar app named Celestia. It is also free. I would recommend Stellerium.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you recommend Stellerium over Celestia.