# Any programme that shows actual planet information?

Tags: solar-system

I don't know if this question should be here, if it shouldn't just let me know.

My question is, I'm programming in Java and I want to get the actual stats of the planet, like orbit ,actual temperature etc... Is there any method, package in any language that makes this?

Comment: Have you looked at any open-source space simulators like Celestia and how they store/find this info?

Comment: Did you try a simple web search for "database position planets" ?

Comment: @StephenG I want to take the data in realtime, like space engine does, where is earth right now, how far is neptune from earth right now etc

Comment: Regarding distance between objects "now" : theory of relativity and "now" is complicated, and so is "distance".

Comment: I know it's hard, just asking if there was any autocalculator or database with all the data on specific days, anyway thanks for your help

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488 may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like something that would best be provided by a simple data table which you can open as needed rather than as a feature of the language.  There's one at https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/ that has the basic statistics for the planets (plus Pluto); is that the sort of thing you're after?

Comment: yeah, that's going to be a lot usefull, but I meant, there is anything like in real time(p.ex: orbit position of neptune, distance to the earth at the moment)? Thanks for your answer, I will use it for sure

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez If you search this SE site and Space Exploration SE for the terms "Horizons", "Spice", "Skyfield", "PyEphem" you'll find all kinds of goodies about orbital motion. But real time temperatures of planets will be Weather.com for Earth and nothing for the rest.

Comment: You can get the position on the sky in python from astropy.coordinates.  You'd need to do some trig to get distance to the earth.