# Historical Distance of Planets to Earth

Tags: the-sun, distances, mars, venus, mercury

I'm curious if there is a readily accessible tool available, or simply a reliable way to find out what the distance of the planets in the solar system were on a given date.

For example, if I am trying to determine how far:

1. The Sun
2. Mercury
3. Venus
4. Mars

were from Earth on May 3, 1954 ... how would I do that?

Comment: @uhoh I agree that your answer is better than the question peterh linked to, but is it better than the community wiki answer to [Where can I find/visualize planets/stars/moons/etc positions?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/where-can-i-find-visualize-planets-stars-moons-etc-positions]) I haven't voted as a dupe to that question, but I'm leaning in that direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python

I see that you are quite active in Stack Overflow but have no posts tagged with `python` yet, so maybe it's time to give it a try!

1. Run `pip install skyfield`
2. read the simple documentation: https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/
3. calculate x, y, z positions in the solar system's coordinates with a single line of Python; e.g. `x, y, z = venus.at(time).position.km, or
4. use `Topos` to define a viewing location on Earth and the `.altaz()` method to get the position of each in the sky.

### NASA JPL Horizions

This is the same basic source of information that Skyfield uses.

1. Go to the Horizons website at: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi
2. Follow the instructions I've written up in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25357/12102).
3. You can also read the documentation there to specify topographic coordinates and get positions in the sky, and you can do that *viewing from other planets and bodies as well!*

Have fun!

Comment: Moved this answer [to here instead](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29639/7982).

Comment: That was too hasty, now moved it back here again.