# Historic observational data - position of the planets

Tags: planet, data-analysis, raw-data

Is there an online source where historic observational data regarding the position of the planets can be found? I was always intrigued by the fact that Neptune was mathematically predicted before it was actually observed ([wiki article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_of_Neptune).

I am curios in finding more about this mathematical prediction regarding the existence of Neptune. Here are a few questions related to this:

- Are there any detailed references on the subject?
- Is it possible to find the data which lead to this discovery online somewhere?
- Are there online resources regarding the position of the planets (now or at various points in the past)?

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/ may or may not be helpful. The Royal Observatory in England has been publishing predicted planetary positions for something like 1000 years, but these are predicted, not observed.