# Simulate earth, moon, sun constellation with dates

Tags: the-sun, the-moon, earth, n-body-simulations

I would like to simulate the three object distance, specifically the distance of the moon to both, sun and earth for further investigation into tide prediction.

What would be a good starting point to browse?
Do any (preferably python) libraries exist for this?
My use is to query the function with a date and it would spit out the distance.

A first model I would be happy to start with would be basic circular trajectories and expand to elliptical & inclinations from there.

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/ might be a good start

Comment: Hi @ElDude for Python solutions my personal recommendation is to use [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) as a quick, self-contained solution. It downloads an ephemeris and interpolates it for you in a very pythonic way, so with just a few lines you can get everything you want, including "query wtih a date and spit out the distance" using [`.separation_from()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36323725/3904031).

Comment: Check [issue #228](https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/issues/228) for updates on constellations. See barrycarter's comment above for a wide range of options. Consider closing as dupicate(?) or perhaps refine your question to something specific that's not answered there?