# how to plot sky map like www.nakedeyeplanet.com with dates tags with planetary motion path

Tags: declination, astrometry, right-ascension

I am curious how to plot planetary motion star chart with date tags like on www.nakedeyeplanets.com by Martin J. Powell.

Is there any way to generate images similar like that. What software should be used MATLAB or what.

Also should have following features:
 - constellation boundaries 
 - non-overlapping naming of star,constellation
 - different color for planet path for each year

Example, click for full size:

[image: example chart for Jupiter from Martin J. Powell's www.nakedeyeplanets.com]

Comment: This question initially looks like planetarium software requirements, asking for a design. Could you narrow it down a bit?

Answer (score 2):

The Python program Skyfield can generate the data for most of this. It can for example generate curves for planet trajectories, provide star positions and magnitudes from a catalog, and even generate boundaries for the constellations.

- https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api.html

Then Matplotlib or Plotly can be used in the same python script to make plots as nice-looking as you like.

There may be other canned programs that can do this as well, just for example [Stellarium](http://stellarium.org/) and [Celestia](https://celestia.space/).

For further resources, see answers to [Where can I find/visualize planets/stars/moons/etc positions?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982)

and the animation in [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/34815/7982)