# Information about known objects in the Universe

Tags: distances, photography, coordinate

I want to retrieve coordinates, photos, and information (size, atmosphere composition, distance from Earth, etc.) about every known object in the universe. Ideally, the information is available via an Application Programming Interface (API) for easy retrieval via a computer program.

What is the best free source of this information? Thank you for your help.

Comment: At first I wanted to just dismiss your question as ridiculous but it's not. There are certainly a lot of different databases out there, I wonder if there is just one interface that can access all of them and perhaps even remove duplicate entries. I'll bet a SpaceCoin that no such thing exists, but I haven't a clue really.

Comment: What about Aladin?

Comment: There is no single database for every object we know giving you every property. You will have to make selections of your own and then access the individual databases. Sorry.

Comment: You should probably narrow down what you mean by "object". Many objects don't even have the same type of parameters, so it makes little sense to list them in the same database. E.g. galaxies don't have atmospheres, comets don't have ionization fractions, and molecular clouds don't have orbital periods.

Comment: Wolfram seems to have a large bunch of stuff, eg https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StarData.html?view=all

Comment: Technically, "known objects in the universe" includes you, me, and literally everything on and inside the Earth. The closest you'll get to that list is probably wikipedia.org or wikidata.org. Having said that, http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/ lists several astronomy catalogs, but I don't think there's a single source for everything. Even wikipedia/data won't have every single star in the GAIA catalog, of course

Comment: Start with Simbad  http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/  Here's the result of a search that will at least get you started down the right path  http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=NGC+1275&submit=SIMBAD+search The Identifiers may or may not contain additional object information

Comment: You could start here, https://github.com/amnh/HackTheUniverse/wiki/Dataset-Resources

Comment: The proposed close reason "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only" seems wrong to me. The question asks for one single thing, a database of all objects. If the answer is that it's too hard to make a database like that, then *that's the answer* not the close reason!

Comment: Here is a link to exoplanet data. https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/docs/KeplerMission.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's an API: [Documentation for Catalog/Image webservices provided by CASG/MAST](http://gsss.stsci.edu/Software/WebServices.htm).

You can also find more search resources in Github, e.g. [HackTheUniverse](https://github.com/amnh/HackTheUniverse/wiki/Dataset-Resources).

Comment: `+1` I always try to add a little more information as text. If/when the link breaks or rots it in the future, will be easier to figure out where it went.

Comment: That's basically just a subset of star catalogs and HST observations. The SIMBAD API would be much better: http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/Pages/guide/sim-url.htx