# Software apps for calculating distances between planets

Tags: planet, distances, software

Are there somewhere any software apps for calculating distances between any planets in our solar system?

Comment: Have a look at the amazing answer to [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982) and see if you think you can find what you need there. If not, can you edit your question and add some details or explain why none of those will work? I know it's a long list, so if you can mention if you can use Python, or if you are using a laptop or computer, or a phone for a device, that will help narrow it down.

Comment: Also, do you need recent numbers only (say +/-50 years) or might you want to go hundreds or thousands of years in the past and/or future? Thanks, and *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*