# Search satellite locations on the sky by date and coordinates

Tags: software, ephemeris

I would like to know what satellites, asteroids, comets, etc passed through a certain coordinate or region on the sky at a certain date. I have found sites like NASA's [HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi#top), but this searches for coordinates for a specific object only. Does a tool to perform this type of generalized search exist?

Comment: You could try Stellarium. I don't know if it retains historic orbital elements, or if it just uses the current ones.

Comment: If you have at least a little experience with Python, then the [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) package will allow you to grab the necessary orbital data for thousands of satellites, asteroids and comets from standard databases and propagate their orbits and project on to the celestial sphere as seen by a given location on Earth at a given time in a very straightforward manner. Then it's a simple task to sort them to see if they fit in a specific window or not.

Comment: Also, see: [Obtain archived TLE data](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/obtain-archived-tle-data).

Comment: and see [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488)