# Astronomical resources helpful for creating an animation in the browser of the movements of an astronomical object in the sky?

Tags: black-hole

#### Background

I would like to create a website that shows an animation of the path of Sagittarius A* (or any other object in space) during one day for a specific location. So that the user can see where and when Sagittarius A* is rising, what path across the sky it takes and where and when it is setting.

Similar to this:

I know the animation in the YouTube video was made with "Stellarium Web" and I could make something like that with Stellarium for Sagittarius A*. But I would like to have it interactive on a website where the user only has to enter his current location and then would see the animation of the path for his location.

#### Question

Where can I find astronomical resources for getting the data necessary to make such a plot in a way useful for a website? It would have to be something I could call from, or incorporate into a website, not a stand-alone program.

Comment: I think there are several posts here and in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) that will be helpful, and it might be worth searching yourself to see if anything suits your needs. There is one page of resources here [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982).

Comment: Making a website simulate spots on a blank screen is one thing, adding a horizon and foreground objects is another; it's a big project, so any more details you can add will be great. For example, what computer and website programming languages are you willing to use and/or learn?

Comment: How are you experienced in programming? Do you understand the concept of OOP? JavaScript is a language, specially designed for browsers. Consider using some popular JavaScript 3d libraries, for example three.js, babylon.js, or WebGL.

Comment: This question is duplicate to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387952/how-to-create-a-web-animation-of-the-movements-of-an-object-in-space-over-time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This is not an astronomy question, but a programming one.

Comment: @User123 Well spotted, although we call that a cross-post, not a duplicate, since the usual processes regarding duplicates (like duplicate flagging & close-voting, and the system software that links duplicates) don't apply to questions on other sites.

Comment: Please do not cross-post. However, that question is far too broad for Stack Overflow, which is for answering questions about specific problems with your code.

Comment: Plotting the movement of astronomical bodies in the sky is on-topic. We can simply constrain the question a little bit rather than insta-close it. **voting to keep open** and making a helpful edit.