# Constellation search from April 22 2007

Tags: constellations

I need help. I am trying to find the night sky on April 22, 2007, over Memphis, TN. I know that there has to be some way to find it, and I am at a loss.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/where-can-i-find-the-positions-of-the-planets-stars-moons-artificial-satellit)

Comment: @ConnorGarcia I've just asked [Is insta-closing of potential duplicates always the best way? In low Q-rate sites? Is there something to be said for slow-closing or eventual closing?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/7982)

Answer (score 5):

Stellarium is a well-known and reliable piece of software to get a view of the sky either in real-time or at a time and place of your choice. You can download it for your OS, or you can use the web version (my preference for quick searches) [here](https://stellarium-web.org/).

You should be able to select your location and set the date and time. You can then search for the constellation or group of stars that you want either manually or through one of the catalog searches.

Answer (score 4):

For a large list of options, see answers to [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982)

However, [in-the-sky.org](https://in-the-sky.org/) is my favorite source online.

Select the Planetarium option. It will automatically choose a location on Earth and time zone based on where you are connected to the internet, but you can always set those to anything you want manually.

---

in-the-sky.org planetarium mode for Memphis, TN, 22-Apr-2007 10 PM CST looking west. The three purple dots are Saturn, the Moon, and Venus.

[image: in-the-sky.org planetarium mode for Memphis, TN, 22-Apr-2007 10 PM CST]

---

There's also an orrery:

[image: in-the-sky.org orrery mode for Memphis, TN, 22-Apr-2007 10 PM CST]

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was super helpful

Answer (score 4):

The night sky is visible in [this viewer](https://skyandtelescope.org/interactive-sky-chart/) from Sky and Telescope.  Simply launch the viewer, set your location, date, and time, and see the night sky as it appeared at that time.  You may step through the viewed scene hour by hour, and even see the sky from a selected view looking in any direction.  Everything is there... planets, sky features, constellations...  Take a look!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about Sky and Telescope's viewer! I remember having to buy a subscription and wait for an issue to arrive in the mail each month! :-)