# Tables or software for some astronomical data

Tags: planet, data-analysis, visualization

Recently I saw a beautiful (but not rare) phenomenon - Jupiter was "directly above" the Moon, that is, they had the same azimuth and a small difference in altitude.

I would like to see on the graphs how the altitude between the planets changes at those moments when they have the same azimuth.
Preferably hour by hour.

I can't find suitable software, tables (for downloads as files) or formulas!

Comment: One option is Horizons: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/

Comment: several options in the answer to [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982) As PM2Ring points out JPL Horizons would be great and if you like Python then [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) is perfect!